# 'watir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: watir

I'm getting this from cmd. Windows 10.
'watir' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
In all the consultation people say that the problem is on Environment Variables.
I can not figure out.
Help is appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Watir is not a stand alone program. See our Getting Started guides (http://watir.com/guides/), and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I followed the instructions from your link, to installing Watir and get this from the cmd: 'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Reinstall ruby and make sure you select to add ruby to path

Comment: Hi, I reinstall Ruby and is ok, now,